# Stretch children proportionally inside StackPanel

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

There's a `StackPanel`

```
<StackPanel x:Name="sp1" Orientation="Horizontal" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" />
```

which is dynamically populated with rectangles:

```
var values = new[] { 30, 50, 20 };
foreach (int val in values)
{
    sp1.Children.Add(new Rectangle
    {
        // Width = perecntage, not supported on Rectangle
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
        Fill = new SolidColorBrush(colors.Pop()),
    });
}
```

`Width` has to be a proportion of the parent's width based on `val`.

I've tried to set it via the `SizeChanged` event, but this works only for enlarging. Shrinking the window doesn't bring the width back.

```
sp1.SizeChanged += (sender, args) => 
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var val in values)
    {
        var prop = (double)val / valuesSum;
        var r = (Rectangle)sp1.Children[i++];
        r.Width = (int)(prop * args.NewSize.Width);
    }
}
```

The only objective is to have a bar that is proportionally divided and stretched. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by calling `child.Arrange()`, which lets you set `X`.

The child has to have `Width` unset, otherwise it takes precedence.

```
sp1.SizeChanged += (sender, e) => 
{
   var childRect = new Rect(0, 0, 0, e.NewSize.Height);

   for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
   {
       var childWidth = (double)values[i] / valuesSum * e.NewSize.Width;
       childRect.Width = childWidth;

       so1.Children[i].Arrange(childRect);

       childRect.X += childWidth;
   }
}
```

I tried `RelativePanel` and `StackPanel` and both worked the same.

This can also be done in a class derived from `Panel`. The code is the same, but it's called from overridden `ArrangeOverride()`.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't entirely clear why you want to use a `StackPanel` for this. A StackPanel grows as it's contents get larger, the individual controls are 'stacked' to fit into the space available to the StackPanel. That doesn't match your requirements for *"a bar that is proportionally divided and stretched"*.

If you use something like a `Grid`, you can define the columns and rows to be proportionally spaced. For example, a Grid with two columns whose widths are defined as `2*` and `3*` those columns will be two-fifths of the width of the Grid, and three-fifths (fifths because 2+3=5). Needless to say, you can have as many columns as you like, and define the relative sizing as you require, possibly using 30*,50*,20* from information in the question. Or if you take the stars away, the values become literal values rather than relative values.

If you just want something to evenly space things out, try a `UniformGrid`. You can limit the number of columns or rows.

If you have some complex need which is not covered by anything else, you can write a custom container control.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I don't insist on `StackPanel`, but I need a variable amount of children (bars) where each has a proportional width based on dynamically populated `values`. So something like a horizontal `StackPanel` that shrinks with its parent.

Comment: Taking the Grid example above, if you populated the column definitions dynamically, based on the `values`, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Good idea, I didn't realize `Grid` can have runtime definitions. I'm using a class derived from `Panel` with the code in my answer, which is more straightforward. `Grid` derives from `Panel` as well, so I don't expect performance differences.